# How can I see the history of stories I've read on Apple News?

Tags: apple-news

Sometimes I'll be interrupted in the middle of reading a story on Apple News and later when I open the app, it didn't save the story I was previously reading. I want to be able to resume reading the article, how can I find it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the "History" of your viewed articles!

**iOS:**
Click the "Following" tab on the bottom right, and click on "History" toward the top.

**Mac:**
Show the sidebar and click on "History" toward the top.