# Why does the News app lose the article you're reading when restoring

Tags: ios, apple-news

This is super, super annoying.  If I open the News app on my phone, start reading an article and then, say, reply to a message; every time I restore the article the News app just goes back to the home screen.

I'd expect this if my phone was running out of memory but it's not.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?  Seems like a bug.

Comment: What version of iOS are you on?

Comment: Are you sure that having an article open, sending a message, and then immediately returning: results in the article going away? In my experience it persists for at least an hour.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple News iOS app does go back to the home screen if left inactive, I can't comment as to what triggers this and why - but I can offer a [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354983/151404):

You can find the "History" of your viewed stories within the "Following" tab (bottom right).